# Using the DnnUserProfileDataSource, How do you turn the Photo back in to a path/URL?

Tags: 2sxc

Using the DnnUserProfileWhen I include the User Profile field, "Photo" in my Query, I get back a number. This is the FileID of the previously uploaded user profile photo. Is there some utility method that would allow me to easily convert that back to a path/filename or relative URL so I can use it in my Razor output? How do I get 417 converted to "/Portals/0/Users/020/20/20/headshot.jpg"?

Using DNN 9.02.02 and 2sxc 9.42

How do I get 417 converted to "/Portals/0/Users/020/20/20/headshot.jpg"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DNN FileManager. Here sample code from 2sxc: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/blob/01bca1f263213c6ac8ec1ae1cecb52901cbbb970/2sxc%20Dnn/Environment/Dnn7/EavImplementation/DnnValueConverter.cs#L92-L110